# What is program collision?/Can a namespace prevent collisions?

Tags: c#, collision

I've done some google searches for just what program collision is and how to prevent it with no results for C# or even a generic answer. I'm thinking collisions would be if one variable has the same name as another or possibly 2 classes with the same name on accident.

Comment: I don't think 'program collision' is a standard piece of terminology. Where did you hear it?

Comment: I've never heard the term before... it would be helpful if you'd give some context of where *you've* heard of it.

Comment: Try to avoid same name class names even in different namespaces in a solution.

Comment: I've heard people use the word "collision" to mean "a crash due to a bad driver"... but I think they were talking about cars at the time.

Comment: I've heard of a programme collision, but I was trying to watch two TV shows at the time

Comment: Namespace collision? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(VS.80).aspx

Comment: we are colliding with this question but OP has yet not given any clue.. :D

Comment: I heard it from my teacher in my current class at Devry. He mentioned it and said it would be on my final and i have no idea what it is. >_>

Comment: @allthosemiles ask your teacher? At this rate, Stack Overflow would fail your final.

Comment: I'll have to it seems. :| If it's not online then i'm guessing he's calling it the wrong name or something. >___> Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He was just talking about when two variables have the same name or two classes. That's all. -_-'